# How to display wms layer in android application using cesium and geoserver?

Tags: android, flutter, webview, geoserver, cesiumjs

I try add wms layer on cesium globe to display in android application. I'm using [flutter webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin v0.3.21, geoserver v2.15.1 and cesium v1.69.

I get this errors and warnings in real device and emulator:

E/libEGL  (23338): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
W/cr_media(23338): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
W/AudioCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime audio/alac
W/AudioCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime audio/dsd
W/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime video/divx
W/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime video/divx311
W/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime video/divx4
W/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
I/VideoCapabilities(23338): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/flutter (23338): Open html file (for cesium) in FLUTTER Webview
I/flutter (23338): flutter test webview
I/chromium(23338): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile X: 0 Y: 0 Level: 0.", source: https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.68/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js (1)
I/chromium(23338): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)]
.................
An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile X: 3 Y: 1 Level: 1.", source: https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.68/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js (1)

Here is sourcecode

cesium.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.69/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.69/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
          rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="cesiumContainer" style="width: 100%; height:300px"></div>
<script>
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
var url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/'; //Geoserver URL
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
    layers.removeAll();
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,
        layers: 'workspace:layer_name' 

    }));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: LocalHtmlPage()));

class LocalHtmlPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OpenHTMLPageState createState() => _OpenHTMLPageState();
}

class _OpenHTMLPageState extends State<LocalHtmlPage> {
  WebViewController _webViewController;
  String filePath = 'assets/cesium.html';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Cesium  Example')),
        body: WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _webViewController = webViewController;
            _loadHtmlFromAssets();
          },
          onPageStarted: (url) {
            //Invoked when a page starts loading.
            print('Open html file (for cesium) in FLUTTER Webview');
            EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            print('flutter test webview');
            EasyLoading.dismiss(animation: false);
          },
        ));
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileHtmlContents = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
    _webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,
            mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.21
  flutter_easyloading: ^1.1.4
  easy_web_view: ^1.2.0
```

Comment: Likely you are trying to use a webview app version that cannot properly interpret this code, try with last webview versión and see if it properly works there.

Comment: Thanks but I already used last flutter webview v0.3.21 (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). The main.dart works with another html files. But it doesn't work with this cesium.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try putting your code into Cesium Sandcastle and see if it works.

Here is a sample of Cesium Sandcastle displaying maps from a local GeoServer.

[Cesium Sandcastle with GeoServer example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bVHRSsMwFP2VS582GMl8G7Ubyh5E2FCouJe8ZMm1DaZJSdKOKf67SStY5/IQuOeec+7JTc8d9ApP6GANBk+wRa+6hrwO2IxlYqi31gSuDDqWzW+ZYYZSuJcSOBz2JaiGV+jOoPk5MkwfPX+gXUJ8tB5nkD9wNPpTEy7l4wg8O9srmQIYmMY64HHP2xJdrwRecj8TGaBzOgeW1SG0OaXaCq5r60O+Wq6WtELroxodPTWeZYtRMgT3SRVs2+Y+8IC/3aC0MlUpamwwn6Z5QFs53tZKvEwos3mSfcU7rQqyRVb4cNa4Gd0A7lTTWhdS0BkhNGDT6jSQHjvxjoEI7wdlPAWdSgupelByfeVXQGjufey8dVqX6gNZtilo5P+TastlzPoUdxCfnWj1zWY3goSQgsbyujJYq4/cXTh/Aw)

If the Cesium Sandcastle fails, **you will have to enable CORS in GeoServer**.  Go to GeoServer's webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml and un-comment all CORS sections then restart GeoServer.
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors

Comment: My code and your example works, I tested them. But this examples not working in flutter app. I don't show map from geoserver. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or missing.

Comment: If the Cesium Sandcastle can display your GeoServer map and you use the same Cesium WebMapServiceImageryProvider code in your Flutter app then you need to debug from Flutter.  https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging OR https://medium.com/flutter-community/three-easy-ways-to-debug-network-requests-in-flutter-53043e898929